# Sublime Text 2 console output to file?

Tags: sublimetext2

How can I get Sublime Text 2 to write output from the Console to the current file?

This could be useful for something like looping a list to generate repetitive output. Here's a contrived example:

```py
# Console:
>>> pets = ['dog', 'cat', 'bird', 'fish']
>>> print '<ul>\n<li>%s</li>\n</ul>' % '</li>\n</li>'.join(pets)
```

Is there a command to send that output to the insertion point of the file I'm working on?

Note that I am not looking to run the current file in a console window, I'm looking to run a snippet from the console to generate code in the current file.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `insert` command:

```
>>> pets = ['dog', 'cat', 'bird', 'fish']
>>> output = '<ul>\n<li>%s</li>\n</ul>' % '</li>\n</li>'.join(pets)
>>> view.run_command("insert", {"characters": output})
```

Comment: That works, but I'm holding out for something simpler and cleaner.